# Find the position in the line of text file

Tags: python

Im trying to find the position in a file of certain string. I know how to find the line, but I need to find the exact position in the line of a string.

```
    curzt2 = open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\world\\program\\maps\\default\\world"+str(i)+".ZT2", "r+")
    content = curzt2.read()
    #find the line in the file
    curzt2line = content.index('terrFile="terrain.dat"')
    curzt2.seek(curzt2line, 0)
    curzt2.write(str(i))
    curzt2.close()
```

for example in this file I want to read to this line

```
<ZTWorldMgr version="0" environment="world/environments/env1wetlands_medium.xml" tankenv="" terrFile="terrain.dat" camPitch="-0.000000" camYaw="-2.233864" camRoll="-0.000000" loadCount="1453" safehandledobjid="3">
```

and change terrain.dat to terrai+str(i)+.dat

Comment: Please share some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Ok I added an example

Comment: It is so much easier to just create a new file. Did you try that?

Comment: No I haven't. Any advice on doing that? Thanks.

Comment: What is variable i, as in `str(i)`?